# IntelliJ IDEA - How to structure Modular Kotlin Multiplatform projects (Android/iOS)

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I just used IntelliJ to create a Kotlin (Mobile Android/iOS) project.

The outcome of using IntelliJ is a **coupled** shared project and Android app

[image]

The Android UI code lives in the **main** folder above.

I’m wondering why IDEA doesn’t do this on a more modular level. So something like this:

- Separate Android Module
- Separate Shared Module

Where the android module uses the shared one and the shared one is also compiled into the framework for iOS

Has anyone successfully structured their project like this with correct test configurations as well?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of a project structure you wish in the official [tutorial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/mpp-ios-android.html). It has a shared module and two platform-specific modules.

---

About the reason for the current situation. It aims to, as far as I can see, provide an example of a single-module multi-platform project. So, it was specially designed to have this structure.

Comment: I've seen this one before but it doesn't really enable testing right out of the box. I was looking for a template i could follow directly to avoid mistakes etc

Comment: Oh, I see. I personally recommend talking with other developers inside the kotlin slack rather than ask here. There was a lot of conversations about testing in MPP.